# How do i refer to window opened by link (a tag)

Tags: javascript

If i were to open a new window using javascript and write `window.open(....` then i could set it as a variable then i could do something with it but with link opening  a new window using `target = _blank` the window seems inaccessible to me. So is there a way to access it.

Comment: Please provide some code to supplement your question. It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You cannot. If browsers would allow that, then malicious scripts would conveniently make users work on websites which are totally manipulated by the malicious script.

Comment: if it's so dangerous than why can you control the newly opened window that is created using javascript as in `window.open();`

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible to do if you specify any other url than something like `about:blank`. If you use `window.open` to create a popup, then insert the HTML code you need on that popup via DOM manipulation, for example:

```
popupWin.document.body.innerHTML = 'your body content here'
```

then you are free to modify the contents. If you load another url via `window.open` though, it would be a major security issue for other sites that would be loaded in a popup, so to answer the question: editing the contents of a popup loaded from a url is not possible.

Comment: i guess it does makes sense. Beside anything that you can do from parent window to your own page is something you can do at your own page.